# Sorting a vector that contains pair<x,y>

Tags: c++, vector, std-pair

I have seen a code somewhere in which a guy did something like this

```
#define pp pair<int,int>
int main()
{
  int n,i;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  vector<pp> G;
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
     int x,y;
     scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);
     G.push_back(pp(x+y,x-y));
  }
  sort(G.begin(),G.end());
```

I want to know how sorting is done here. I mean to say **on what parameter sorting is performed in a vector that contains pairs in it**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sort` function sort according to an comparaison function (which defines the order). One could want to specify which omparaison to use, however if the comparaison function is not specified (like in your case) then `sort` uses the defaut order being the `<` operator on the considered object

So in your case, ordering is possible because the comparaison operator is overloaded for `std::pair`.

The behaviour of those operator is described here : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp

Therefor, when sorting the `<` operator on the `std::pair` class will be called, and your pairs are going to be ordered lexicographically

```
(0,1) < (0,2) < (1,0) < (1,2) < (2,7)
```

Comment: can you please elaborate a little bit ?

Answer (score -1):

Check this link: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/operators/

> Similarly, operators <, >, <= and >= perform a lexicographical comparison on the sequence formed by members first and second.

So, `a < b` means `(a.first < b.first) || (a.first == b.first && a.second < b.second)`

Comment: Note equivalence for a strict weak ordering (which `std::sort` mandates from its comparator) does not need to invoke `operator ==`.  Ex: `(a.first < b.first) || (!(b.first < a.first) && a.second < b.second)` is common as it reduces the number of required operators on the type of `first` to only `operator <`